# Which book to start learning Jeet Kune Do

Tags: self-training, recommendation, jeet-kune-do, books

I have both of the following books and I want to know which one is better to start with. I am absolutely beginner and unfortunately there is no class for Jeet Kune Do in my area.

- **Tao of Jeet Kune Do : New Expanded Edition**
- **Bruce Lee's Fighting Method : The Complete Edition**

In the introduction section of the second one by M.Uyehara, he expresses that Tao of Jeet Kune Do is meant to complement this book. However, I'm still not sure which one is a better starting point.

Comment: I guess it is irrelevant with which you start. Quedtions that arise reading one may be answered in the other. You will know when you finished both.

Comment: I have to start with something , right?!!
Which one do you suggest?

Comment: As I said, it is irrelevant really. But personally, I'd start with "Tao of JKD" to have the master himself have the first impression on you.

Comment: If you want to learn about Plato, then you read Plato. You only read other people's opinions on Plato once you've actually read The Republic, The Symposium, The Cave, etc. Martial-arts-via-book is no different.

Answer (score 5):

Buy the Tao of Jeet Kune Do.

Because Reasons:

- The Tao of Jeet Kune Do is Bruce's treatise on his philosophy - the philosophy which underpins his later teachings.
- Absolute beginners should find teachers, not books, to learn technique from.  You can try copying the stuff in "Bruce Lee's Fighting Method", but until you already have a basis in martial arts, the best you can do is mimicry.

Find a qualified martial arts instructor.  It is especially auspicious if you find a Wing Chun, or Kali instructor, as these arts will fit in best with JKD.  If you can't find those, just find a good instructor, whether that's in Kenpo or Kickboxing.  You can always do JKD later, when it becomes available.  And, because of the JKD philosophy, none of your training in other arts will have been wasted.

Later, once you have a basis in martial arts, there's no harm in looking over the drills in Bruce Lee's Fighting Method.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a Jeet Kune Do school but you want to learn something similar, look for an MMA gym. Mixed Martial Arts is an outflow of Jeet Kune Do. To such an extent that Bruce Lee is referred to as "The Father of MMA". Wing Chun comprises a large portion of Jeet Kune Do, but your chances of finding a Wing Chun school that teaches proper Wing Chun are pretty low. You are more likely to find yourself at a Master Joe's Wing Chun and hot babes Yoga school, which is a waste of time unless you happen to be Master Joe.

Answer (score 0):

Tao of JKD is just his notes. While it's good to have as a reference, you would be better off with something more practical. Check Sifu Kevin Seaman's books or Sifu Lamar Davis' books.

Comment: Why are Sifu Kevin Seaman's books or Sifu Lamar Davis' books better than a reference manual?